# Angular bindings in href work but src bindings do not?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular and I am trying to learn about it via the tutorial on their own site.

[Link to the step I am currently on](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_06)

Now what I understand from this particular step is that I can user `href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}"` and Angular will bind the `{{phone.id}}` when processing but in order to bind the `src` attribute it needs the `ng-src` attribute or otherwise the browser will process the `{{ expression }}` markup literally.

Why is it that `src` does not work with Angular binding but `href` does? Why don't we need `ng-href` or something like it to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the browser tries to download the image from the `src` attribute while rendering the html page. So when the page is rendered for the first time, the browser will parse the expression as the image source, and will return 404.

What Angular is doing with `ng-src` is resolving the image path and updating the `src` attribute after the expression is evaluated.

But in case of `href` inside an anchor, it is just string parsing, browser does not have to download any thing. The `href` attribute will get updated after the expression is evaluated and the browser will get the change.

Answer (score 1):

> Using Angular markup like {{phone.id}} in an href attribute will make the
>   link go to the wrong URL if the user clicks it before Angular has a
>   chance to replace the {{phone.id}} markup with its value. Until Angular
>   replaces the markup the link will be broken and will most likely
>   return a 404 error.

The ngHref directive solves this problem.

The wrong way to write it:

```
<a href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}">Possibly broken phone</a>
```

The correct way to write it:

```
<a ng-href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}">Working phone</a>
```

This is straight from the AngularJS docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

**On your example, the img src must be using the ng-src, since the image is loaded automatically ASAP the page starts to load and angular does not have a chance to replace it.**

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Answer (score 0):

From ngSrc doc:

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in an href attribute will make the
>   link go to the wrong URL if the user clicks it before Angular has a
>   chance to replace the {{hash}} markup with its value.

In fact, using *href* is unsafe method.

But src not waiting nothing, browser get src while rendering - and throw exception.